# I am unable to get the proper syntax for my Goal Seek routine

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my routine.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' Mass Goal Seek

    Dim Taddr, Gaddr, Aaddr As Range
    Dim currPart As String
    Dim MaxParts, prt As Integer
    Dim ARange, TRange, GRange As Range
    Dim NumEq, i As Long

    MaxParts = 15
    For prt = 1 To MaxParts
        currPart = Worksheets("Data Entry").Range("Header")(prt)
        Worksheets("Item Data").Range("prt_2").Value = prt
        Set Taddr = ThisWorkbook.Names("TRange").RefersToRange
        Set Aaddr = ThisWorkbook.Names("ARange").RefersToRange
        Set Gaddr = ThisWorkbook.Names("GRange").RefersToRange

        If Worksheets("Data Entry").Range("Header")(prt) Like "Molding***" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        NumEq = Aaddr.Rows.Count

        For i = 1 To NumEq
            'MsgBox ("The Part Number is: " & currPart & " The Value is: " & Taddr(i).Value)

            If Gaddr(i).Value <> "" Then
                Taddr(i).GoalSeek goal:=Gaddr(i), changingcell:=Aaddr(1)
                Gaddr(i).Value = ""
            End If
        Next i
    Next
End Sub
```

The line with the goal seek always errors and I have tried many different syntax lines.
It gives a

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting `Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined` error because the GoalSeek cell `Taddr(i)` must contain a formula that refers directly or indirectly to the ChangingCell `Aaddr(1)`

I would recommend stepping through your code and checking if

1. `Taddr(i)` refers to the cell you think it should refer to
2. It contains a formula which directly/indirectly refers to `ChangingCell`

Here is a simple way to reproduce the error

```
Sub Sample()
    Range("A10").GoalSeek Goal:=100, ChangingCell:=Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Here `A10` doesn't have any formula.

[image]

Now let's add a formula to `A10` referring to `A1` and run the same code

[image]